# How to check in pyodbc package if last impala statement was a select statement?

Tags: python, pyodbc, impala

I would like to have a function based on pyodbc package which runs a query against impala and fetch results if there is something to fetch, otherwise, just execute the statement. Unfortunately, i do not know how to check if i have something to fetch.

```
def execute_my_query(connection, query):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    res = cur.fetchall()
    return res
```

Unfortunately, if i execute something with no result set, such as:

```
execute_my_query(con, 'drop table if exists my_schama.my_table')
```

it fails with the error that there is no result set to return. So i'd like to check if there is a result that i should be returning, and skip if there is no reason to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, i've been able to produce one solution which seems to work in the desired way.

Based on what is written in `pyodbc` [documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) for cursor attribute `description`, the attribute "will be `None` for operations that do not return rows or if one of the execute methods has not been called".

Note that if you wanted to use rowcount attribute instead, this would not work in impala, as you will get `rowcount=-1` even if there is a non-empty result set.

Therefore, one can rewrite the function from the question as:

```
def execute_my_query(connection, query):
    res = None 
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    if cur.description is not None:
        res = cur.fetchall()
    return res
```

That being said, if there is a better way of handling this, i'd still very much like to hear it.